# When is hook_file_download triggered

Tags: hooks

I wonder which files are being considered to go through [hook_file_download](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7). When this function is triggered, what are conditions ?

(Generally, how I can track myself hooks conditions ?)

I am trying to put some custom created download links (files are not uploaded via drupal, but link to them are defined manually, as described in [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66009/allow-downloading-files-from-private-filesystem-when-paths-to-files-are-built-wi).)

**EDIT:** For those searching for hook_file_download related issue, it seems that it is triggered (also) whenever you try to access a valid link to a file in private filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to track where core hooks are called, from core code, is to look on the docs page.

For [`hook_file_download()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7), you'll see this:

[image]

A nice list of all implementations/invocations of the hook with links to the relevant functions.

For the cases that don't get covered there, I usually just grep the codebase for, e.g.

```
module_implements('file_download'
```

That takes me straight to file.inc, and the `file_download()` function, which I guess answers your main question.

If that's not quite enough, I thoroughly recommend using Eclipse/Netbeans with XDebug which will let you set breakpoints to see what's happening in more depth.

Comment: o.O it is triangle toggle icon :) . Somehow I overlooked this for many, many times! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I remember the Eureka moment when I found those triangles too ;)